# Has anyone been able to get sensor data from Moto 360 via. Google Fit API?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os, google-fit, moto-360

I'm referring to the API described here: https://developers.google.com/fit/overview.

I have Google Fit on both my Moto360 and my phone (Nexus 4). I want to retrieve step/heart rate data from the Moto 360 via. the API, but only seem to receive the location data (from my phone) instead. Any help?

I used Google's sample apps located here: https://developers.google.com/fit/android/samples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just check that app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.pocmo.sensordashboard

It is open sourced and whole code is here: https://github.com/pocmo/SensorDashboard

Be sure to take a look at the Sensor manager class: https://github.com/pocmo/SensorDashboard/blob/master/wear/src/main/java/com/github/pocmo/sensordashboard/SensorService.java

Comment: I have the same problem. The moto 360 does not show up on SensorDashboard either.

Comment: @jeremyvillalobos did you ever find a solution to this?  Thanks!  :)